# Docker: Portainer Server vs Agent Only Deployment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, portainer

I just installed [Portainer CE](https://documentation.portainer.io/v2.0/deploy/ceinstalldocker/) by following Docker on Windows WSL / Docker Desktop section as shown below:

Open a terminal and run the following command:

```
create portainer_data
```

And then:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9000:9000 --name=portainer --restart=always 
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer-ce
```

Then login to the system via `http://localhost:9000` without any problem (also define admin pass).

On the other hand, there is an additional section just below the second command as shown below:

> **Portainer Agent Only Deployment** 
> Run the following command to deploy the Agent in your Docker host.
> docker run -d -p 9001:9001 --name portainer_agent --restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/lib/docker/volumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes portainer/agent

Is there any need to use that command and what is the benefit of Portainer Agent exactly? What is Portainer Server vs Agent Only Deployment?

Comment: ["The Portainer Agent is a workaround for a Docker API limitation when using the Docker API to manage a Docker environment. ... The purpose of the agent aims to allow previously node specific resources to be cluster-aware."](https://documentation.portainer.io/archive/1.23.2/agent/).

Comment: Thanks, but I read that page before asking the question, but it is not clear.

Comment: Makes sense in a cluster of multiple nodes, certain `docker` resources (i.e. `volumes`) are local to the node - they are not "cluster-aware". To list the `volumes` using the API you would have to connect to the node. The agent attempts to make those resources cluster-aware (i.e. so you can connect to the manager node and list the `volumes` on all nodes of the cluster).

Comment: Thanks a lot for helps. Do you mean that if the containers are on different machine than my PC, I should install it. If the containers are on my PC, there is no need or benefit installing the agent. Are they completely true?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you’re not using swarm (or kubernetes), you probably won’t ever need to use an agent.

Comment: Thanks you very much. In this case, the place of the containers (on local or on server) does not important for deciding to use agent. The only thing I should keep consideration is using swarm (or kubernetes). Am I right?

Comment: Pretty much, if you’re not using swarm then don’t worry about agents.